# Moving to a screen in a nested navigator React Navigation v5

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v5

### Context

I saw lots of similar questions but no one was a valid answer to my problem.
This is my navigator structure:

```
MainNavigator (mode="modal", headerMode="none")
 - TabNavigator
   - StackHomeNavigator
     - HomeScreen
     - DeadlineScreen
   - ...other tabs
 - StackSettings
   - ScreenSettings
   - UserInfoScreen
   - ConfigureMFA
```

### Description

Usually if I want to navigate to ConfigureMFA I need to click on settings icon which loads the `StackSettings` and present it as a modal. Then I click on "Account Settings" which navigate to `UserInfoScreen` and then I click on "Configure MFA" which navigate to `ConfigureMFA`.
The goal is to navigate from HomeScreen to `ConfigureMFA`. But I also want that, once I'm in `ConfigureMFA` screen I'm able to go back to `UserInfoScreen` and from there go back to `ScreenSettings`.
So basically the navigate history has to be the same as a "manual" navigation.

> Really important: the `HomeScreen` needs to be visible all the time as the `StackSettings` appears as a Modal (think of ModalPresentationIOS).

### What I tried

I tried with `CommonActions.reset` as the documentation suggest. But the app has some strange behavior and flicker. And also I'm not interested on "resetting" my route but instead navigate.

### What I came up

After some researches I came up with this code.
And it works! But the documentation does not say nothing about put `state` as a navigation param.

```
navigation.navigate(AppNavigatorName.SETTINGS, {
  screen: ScreenKeys.configureMfa,
  state: {
    routes: [
      { name: ScreenKeys.settingsScreen },
      { name: ScreenKeys.userInfoScreen },
      { name: ScreenKeys.configureMfa }
    ]
  }
});
```

## Question

Do you guys know why this code works?? Is there any other best practices?

Answer (score 0):

This probably works, which is surprising me, because you're overwriting the navigation state. I do not think it is recommended. The way you can solve this is by using **navigation.reset**

```
navigation.reset({
    index: 2,
    routes: [
        { name: ScreenKeys.settingsScreen },
        { name: ScreenKeys.userInfoScreen },
        { name: ScreenKeys.configureMfa }
    ],
});
```

This way react-navigation will reset and rebuild it's own state correctly and when you hit back from your Settings screen you should go back to Home

Comment: Thx for your support but as I said, i already tried with reset action. With reset my new "root screen" becomes the `SettingsScreen`. `SettingsScreen` is a modal which opens on top of `HomeScreen` and so I want that `HomeScreen` stays visible